# Difficult Integral Involving Both Trignometry and x To a High Power

Tags: integration

Find the integral 
$$\int x ( 4 + x^{99} )\sin(x) dx$$

Okay so I'm assuming this integral should be solved somehow by parts but I couldn't figure it out at all. 
Is the x outside the brackets supposed to be a hint?

Please help!

Comment: Try integration by parts on $\int x^n \sin x \, dx$, you'll get a recurrence for the integral.

Answer (score 1):

For the general $\int x^n\sin x\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^{k+1}x^{n-2k}{n!\over(n-2k)!}\cos x+\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}(-1)^kx^{n-2k-1}{n!\over(n-2k-1)!}\sin x$

Consider solving the recurssion, 
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n &=& \int dx \ x^n e^{i x} = \int dx \ x^n \sin x + i \int dx \ x^n \cos x \\
&=& - i\int dx \ \left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^n e^{i x}\right) - n x^{n-1} e^{i x}\right] \\
&=& - i \left(x^n e^{i x} - n a_{n - 1}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

and take the real part.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But I don't really understand, the math is too complex for my level of knowledge. 
So basically, does this mean that there is no simple solution to the integral that could be achieved with basic knowledge of integration like substitution and parts?

Comment: @user130996 Well, no - there is a simple solution. What has shown is just a way to solve this sort of equation (in fact, r9m's used $\int x^n\sin xdx$) generally. This can be solved using integration by parts and substitution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want integration by parts, then
$$\int x(4+x^{99})\sin(x)=\int (4x+ x^{100})\sin(x)dx=-\int (4x+ x^{100})d(\cos(x))\\
=-\left((4x+ x^{100})(\cos(x))-\int\cos(x)d(4x+ x^{100})\right)$$
Hope this helps.

Comment: Wrong way.  This would give you larger powers of $x$ when you do the integration by parts.  You want to integrate the trig function and differentiate the polynomial.

Comment: @RobertIsrael but then wouldn't you have to do it 99 times?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I edited my answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Why do you go from sin(x) dx to d(cosx)? And why is it 4xsin(x) and not 4xsin(x) + x^100sin(x) ?

Comment: $sin(x)=-d(cosx)/dx$, and the second mistake was a typo.